# Getting conversations from Microsoft Graph API Messages

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to get the most recent message for each conversationId in a specific folder from Microsoft Graph API. What OData query can get the most recent message for each conversationId from Microsoft Graph API?

I am using their [query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) syntax, but I can't get [aggregation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html) working so that I can use groupby.

```
$apply=groupby(conversationId, topcount(1, createdDateTime))
```

There are no error messages when using the above query. This is expected behavior for Graph API when it does not support the query. I suppose that either my query is wrong or it truly does not support aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Graph does not support aggregation.

Comment: I agree OData aggregation queries are ignored from the testing I have done on mail messages.

Comment: fyi ~ you can create feature requests at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com

Comment: Thank you, a teammate submitted the [feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38715775-implement-odata-extension-for-data-aggregation-ver)

Answer (score -1):

MS Graph API limitations: Microsoft Graph API does not support aggregation functions like groupby, making it difficult to retrieve the latest message for each conversationId.

Linear correspondence without branching: Assuming linear correspondence without branching, ConversationIndex can be used to determine the latest message in each thread.

Using ConversationIndex: The message with the longest ConversationIndex is considered the last in the thread.

Practical implementation: Fetch all messages from the folder using MS Graph API, then select the message with the highest ConversationIndex for each conversationId.

Warning: ConversationIndex may change, affecting the accuracy of determining the last message.